# RequiredFieldValidator not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

When I don't put anything in the textbox, the message is not showing at all after I click a button. Here is my code:

```
    <div style="padding-top:5px">
                        <asp:Label Text="Enter Account Email Address" CssClass="required" runat="server" />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="EAdd" width="300px" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Email"/>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
                          ControlToValidate="EAdd"
                          ErrorMessage="This is a required field."
                          Display="Dynamic"
                          ValidationGroup="Email"
                          ForeColor="Red">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:ValidationSummary id="Errors" ShowMessageBox="true" runat="server" />
                    </div>
```

Comment: where is Button?

Comment: The validator is correct (unless the button has a different ValidationGroup). There are probably javascript errors. Check the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add validation group in your validation summary just like

```
<asp:ValidationSummary id="Errors" ShowMessageBox="true" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Email" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the button have the same ValidationGroup = "Email"?